# What's the difference between Aux Carry and Common Carry in x86 Flags Registers)?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, flags, cpu-registers

I want to know what this x86 register flag means in the DOS/Windows program Debug:

The auxiliary carry (`AC = 1` or `NA = 0`)

Does it have the same meaning as the Common carry? (`CY = 1` or `NC = 0`)

Comment: It would help to know what CPU you are talking about...

Comment: I'll take a guess here and assume you mean x86 ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: yes, it's x86. I should put the **x86** tag?

Comment: It's OK - I've re-tagged for you now. Remember when talking about low level stuff like assembly or CPU architecture that there are a lot more CPUs out there than just x86 so it's important to tag appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auxiliary carry flag is set when an instruction causes a carry or borrow out of bit 3.  Same idea as CY but for the upper bit of the lower nibble in a byte.  The abbreviation AC is old style, the flag is named "AF" in the Intel processor manuals, short for "Adjust Flag".  It is used by a select few x86 instructions that perform BCD calculation adjustments, like AAC (Ascii Adjust after Addition) and DAA (Decimal Adjust after Addition).  These instructions date from the stone age of computing, back when it was still common to supply operands in BCD encoding.  Which encodes a decimal digit in a nibble.  Like decimal 99 is 10011001 in BCD.

It was common back then for processors to have dedicated hardware support for calculations involving BCD.  That's ancient history, programmers got used to encoding numbers in binary.  Well, compilers most of all.  Notable is that these instructions are no longer present in the x64 instruction set.  Making room for more useful 64-bit specific opcodes.

Answer (score 2):

The auxiliary carry flag `AF` watches for a 4-bit (nibble) carry, while the common carry flag `CF` watches for a carry-out from the MSB of the *operand size*.  This could be an 8-bit carry if using 8-bit registers e.g. `al` or `ah`, a 16-bit carry if using 16-bit registers `ax`, and 32-bit or 64-bit carry when using the corresponding registers, e.g. `eax` or `rax` respectively.

Comment: That description of CF is only true for operand-size = 8 bit.  For instructions that set AF (like add/subtract), CF is set according to carry-out from the MSB of whatever the operand-size is.  (Other instructions (e.g. shifts or FP compares) set CF differently).

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's true.  Wanted to highlight the nibble vs. byte comparison, now revised also for correctness.  Thanks!

Comment: Still not quite right.  `add al, bl` sets CF = carry-out from the 8-bit result.  `add ax, bx` sets CF = carry-out from the 16-bit result.  `add rax, rbx` sets CF from the 64-bit result.  All of these instructions are encodeable in 64-bit mode on x86-64.  i.e. CF holds "the carry out" from the last operation, whatever bit position that was.